# What is the fastest way to type math equations at stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I'm trying to learn Latex, but before I go all in it, I want to know what would be the best way to learn it. So I can write math equations as fast as possible. I guess many people have their own solutions of typing latex equations in a fast way. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you look at the questions linked on the right side of this page, under "Related", you will see that several of them link to tips for using TeX and/or LaTeX.

Answer (score 7):

Learn how to us LaTeX and then practice, practice, and practice.

Touch typing helps too.

Answer (score 4):

I tried out a lot of ways to enter equations into a computer.  I think learning LaTeX and getting fast at typing ended up being the best for me.

Here are some other options:

1. Use some kind of text expander system for commonly repeated code.  (Free ones exist like Texter).
2. Use speech recognition software and set it to execute the right key strokes when you say 'bracket' or something like that.  I know the premium version of Dragon Naturally Speaking can do this, but it's pricey.
3. Write equations on a tablet and have it recognized with OCR.

You can find more detail on these options here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr